# When to use Core Data's NSMainQueueConcurrencyType?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is initializing a `NSManagedObjectContext` using `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` only for the situation where that MOC has a child MOC that was initialized using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`?

To give some background: my app has a traditional structure whereby the main table view is driven by a `NSFetchedResultsController` and data are imported asynchronously from a web service using an `NSOperation` subclass that has its own MOC. I wasn't sure whether both MOCs in that situation should use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` (the default, I believe) or whether the MOC associated with the fetched results controller on the main thread should use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and the background MOC should use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First a recipe on Core Data new context types.

`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` creates a context that is associated with the main dispatch queue and thus the main thread. You could use such a context to link it to objects that are required to run on the main thread, for example UI elements.

`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` creates and manages a private dispatch queue to operate on. You must use the new methods `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`. The context will then execute the passed blocks on its own private queue.

Finally, `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is the default type and can be used **only** within the thread where it has been created. So, within your `NSOperation`, you have used it in the right manner. A simple note. If you want to use it as a child context, you need to have a "queue context" (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`).

Now, about your question.

> Is initializing a NSManagedObjectContext using
>   NSMainQueueConcurrencyType only for the situation where that MOC has a
>   child MOC that was initialized using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType?

No, not necessary. Yes, you could set up a private context that does some work in background  and then pushes the retrieved objects to the main one, but I will do the contrary: use a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` as the master context and the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` as a child context for the former. In this way, the main context will deal only with objects that are in memory. Save to disk are performed by the private queue only.

This approach is used by the `UIManagedDocument` class. Save to disk are performed in a background thread (a private queue). In this manner the UI is not freezed.

Comment: @Ricardo Sorry of the delay..I don't have idea...but you could see the code. Cheers.

Comment: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType doesn't always execute blocks on the private queue. With performBlockAndWait it actually locks the queue and performs on the calling thread, which could be the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` is mainly for the contexts linked to the UI.

To keep the UI responsive, most of the business logic is best done in background threads and in "background" contexts. But the UI itself will need to use a context at some point, i.e. `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Child contexts with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` are well suited to editing panes where the changes can be saved at once, ie committed to the parent context. The parent does not need to use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

`NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is the default type. It links the context to the current thread, pretty often the main thread by the way. You shouldn't rely on the default type but in the simplest applications. `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` are best since you precisely know which queue is in use for every context.