# When is it required to use a NSManagedObjectContext with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an NSPersistentDocument for which I'm swapping out the default MOC to one with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` This works well to keep operations off the main thread.

However, do I also need to make a child MOC with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`? What is it needed for, if it's needed at all?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176275/when-to-use-core-datas-nsmainqueueconcurrencytype

Comment: OK having read that I understand that a MainQueue type will be required for 'UI stuff' but what exactly does that mean? Only if I use bindings??

Comment: Not only bindings. If you access any property of the managed object that belong to a context of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` on the main thread, you can do this directly, without wrapping it in `-performBlock:`.

Comment: OK cool I think that answers it – so it IS required for bindings. And can also be used easily in any other situation where we're guaranteed to be on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation on this topic is not very explicit and up to date on the subject. The core data programming guide states: [core data programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)

> The pattern recommended for concurrent programming with Core Data is thread confinement: each thread must have its own entirely private managed object context. [...] You must create the managed context on the thread on which it will be used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Core Data Programming Guide" it not up to date. It does not cover the new concurrency types NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, see ["Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html).